# How to get the current execution role in a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm having issues with a lambda that does not seem have the permissions to perform an action and want to get some troubleshooting information.

I can do this to get the current user:

```
print("Current user: " + boto3.resource('iam').CurrentUser().arn)
```

Is there a way to get the execution role at runtime? Better yet, is there a way to get the policies that are attached to this role dynamically?

They shouldn't change from when I created the lambda, but I want to verify to be sure.

Comment: Have you looked at the `get_caller_identity()` method in boto3. This is under `sts` service. It will return the ARN of the entity attached to the Lambda function.

Answer (score 4):

Do not know, how much relevance this will bring to the OP.

But we can get lambda function configuration at runtime.

```
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
role_response = (lambda_client.get_function_configuration(
    FunctionName = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME'])
)
print(role_response)
role_arn = role_response['Role']
```

`role_response` will have role arn.

`role_response` =>

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '877', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': ''}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'FunctionName': 'lambda_name', 'FunctionArn': 'arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account_id>:function:lambda_arn', 'Runtime': 'python3.8', 'Role': 'arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/<role_name>', 'Handler': 'handlers.handle', 'CodeSize': 30772, 'Description': '', 'Timeout': 30, 'MemorySize': 128, 'LastModified': '', 'CodeSha256': '', 'Version': '$LATEST', 'VpcConfig': {'SubnetIds': [], 'SecurityGroupIds': [], 'VpcId': ''}, 'TracingConfig': {'Mode': 'PassThrough'}, 'RevisionId': '', 'State': 'Active', 'LastUpdateStatus': 'Successful'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this: [list_attached_user_policies](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_attached_user_policies)

> Lists all managed policies that are attached to the specified IAM
>   user.
>
> An IAM user can also have inline policies embedded with it.

If you want just the inline policies: [get_user_policy](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_user_policy)

> Retrieves the specified inline policy document that is embedded in the
>   specified IAM user.

Comment: I would have to know the current user (not the ARN), but since it's an assumed role I'm not sure what that is. I see a message like this: " User: arn:aws:sts::749340585813:assumed-role/golfnow-start-job/dev-StartJobLambda-HZO22Z5IMTFB is not authorized to perform: batch:ListJobs". The other part of the conundrum is my execution role doesn't have privileges to get the current user, and I haven't figured out how to attach policies that would enable privileges to the execution role (otherwise the call that's failing would work).

Comment: ok. My answer is for generic case. In your case, you have to add the required privileges to your Lambda execution role. I think you are not approaching the problem correctly. This is not the way to debug insufficient Lambda privileges.

Comment: The role attached to the Lambda function is `golfnow-start-job`. As @helloV mentioned, you need to make an API call to IAM to get the permissions attached to the role. To get the managed policies attached to the role, you need to invoke `list_attached_role_policies`. To get the list of inline policies attached to the role, you need to invoke `list_role_policies`.