# AWS nodejs SDK check if can access DynamoDB table

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

Using the AWS SDK I can make a get request and fetch a document, I will then know if I have the IAM access to access the database.

Is there a way to test with the NodeJS AWS SDK to see if I have allow access for the action dynamodb:getItem. Of course I can just write a query but is there a way without me having to spend time writing a meaningless query?

Comment: Could of be some use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936470/how-to-get-the-current-execution-role-in-a-lambda

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of right this moment is to try a simple getItem like you mentioned with a primary key, but do it [with the low level API](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/node.js/WorkingWithItems/get-item-low-level.js). Then you are not writing a "meaningless query." If I find another way, I'll add it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check through the user's role through console and CLI as well with the get-user-policy command.

**CLI Approach:**

> aws iam get-user-policy --user-name Bob --policy-name ExamplePolicy

With the help of this command, you check the rights you have on that user. For detail look into this [DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user-policy.html).

**Console Approach:**

- Login with AWS Console and Search IAM service
- Under the User Section, Search your user whose permission need's to check.
- Then in the permission section, you can watch all the permission.