# EC2 Instance IAM Role Credentials in Lambda Function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to pull the EC2 instance IAM Role credentials from the Lambda function. However, it does work when I run simply REST API or script locally on an EC2 instance but not sure I to retrieve EC2 metadata using boto3.

Running below rest endpoint locally is working fine but this does not work via Lambda where the local environment is different.

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/{iam_role}
```

**Use Case:**
I have an IAM Role associated with the EC2 Instance, The same IAM Role is used by many other external applications like ServiceNow, and Salesforce to Invoke other AWS Services, especially API Gateways. To invoke the API gateway from ServiceNow, we need the Access key and secret key of the IAM role. Since EC2 metadata automatically refreshes the Access key and secret key, I want to use that instead of manually rotating secret keys in the IAM role and updating in ServiceNow manually.

Currently, I have a ServiceNow orchestration workflow running on an EC2 instance that returns credentials whenever needed but ServiceNow mid-servers are not stable and I want to get rid of mid-server dependency so trying to achieve this using Lambda. So the approach is reverse engineering in this case Lambda will update the ServiceNow secret manager with the latest credentials before they expire, so any API invoking allowed API Gateway endpoints from ServiceNow can use these credentials for API authorization.

ServiceNow can generate Singture4 authorization but to generate Sign4, it needs ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY that's where the above credentials will be used.

I hope this helps to understand the use case.

*BTW: Lambda and EC2 are in the same region, same account, and deployed within the same VPC*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current execution role in a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936470/how-to-get-the-current-execution-role-in-a-lambda)

Comment: create EC2 resource with `ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2")` and then use `ec2.describe_iam_instance_profile_associations()` and then you can use these profile ARN to view details of these profiles.

Comment: API Gateway supports a [whole bunch of authorization mechanisms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html) which will work much better than what's you proposing. For instance, you can use the Lambda authorizer, which will just say yes/no to your gateway instead of passing the credentials around in a roundabout way. Please post your use case in more detail in a separate post.

Comment: I wish I could use other mechanisms but the API I try to invoke in ServiceNow belongs to multiple teams, and changing authorization won't work. I have tried multiple options but ServiceNow platform's performance and dependency make it more hard.

Comment: This lambda you're trying to implement, who or what invokes it?

Answer (score 3):

Within Lambda context, clients get authenticated from the environmental variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`, which Lambda [sets up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime) for your functions.

boto3 does it out of the box. When you instantiate the client, it will look for credentials [in 8 locations](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#configuring-credentials), stopping on the first found set of credentials. Environment variables are number 3 in this list, EC2 metadata is number 8.

So within a Lambda function, you can just instantiate your client and it will have access to everything your Lambda execution role has access to. You don't need a separate authentication step.

If you for some reason need to get the role ARN explicitly, call [`boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts/client/get_caller_identity.html).

But, as I said, your boto3 client is already authenticated when running inside a Lambda.

Comment: Thanks, @Quassnoi I know the boto3 client is already authenticated when running inside but here I am trying to get credentials and store in the external secret manager periodically for other applications to use these credentials.

Comment: @KP: what kind of credentials do you want to get?

Comment: @KP: it looks like you're trying to implement a custom authorizer (call a lambda, presumably, with one set of credentials like username/password and have it trade them for AWS credentials). If that's true, there are better ways to do that in AWS. If you can expland more on your scenario in a separate post, you will likely get advice on how to do what you're trying to do in a better way.

Comment: thanks again. I have updated the original post with the use case. I hope that helps.